# Como passar um IEnumerable Model para um Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma página que me lista corretamente os meus registros. Mais eu tenho um `Html.BeginForm` para cada linha,

```
@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_POSSIBILIDADE>

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "";
    }


                @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                {

                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {

                        using (Html.BeginForm("GravarRegistro", "Possibilidade", FormMethod.Post))
                        {

                            <div class="container">

                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO01) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR01)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO02) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR02)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA2, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR03)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar para o caixa" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                                    <input type="reset" name="btnLimpar" id="btnLimpar" value="Limpar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                </div>
                            </div>



                        }


                    }

                }
```

Problema: quando eu estou preenchendo os dados e envio a gravação tenho no controle:Mais a tabela está vindo vazia:

```
  public ActionResult GravarRegistro(TB_POSSIBILIDADE tabela)
        {

            try
            {

                string idusuario = (string)Session["idusuario"];
                string titulo    = (string)Session["descricaotitulo"];


                var tTabela = new CaixaAplicacao();
                tTabela.Inseri(idusuario,titulo, tabela.DESCRICAO01,tabela.DESCRICAO02,tabela.DESCRICAO03,
                               tabela.VALOR01,tabela.VALOR02,tabela.VALOR03,tabela.VALORAPOSTA1,tabela.VALORAPOSTA2,
                               tabela.VALORAPOSTA3,tabela.VALORTOTAL1,tabela.VALORTOTALRETORNO );
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["Erro"] = "Não foi possivel gravar o registro.";
                return RedirectToAction("SelecionarPossibilidade", "Possibilidade", new { id = @Session["idpossibilidadde"] });

            }


            return RedirectToAction("SelecionarPossibilidade", "Possibilidade", new { id = @Session["idpossibilidadde"] });
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

html:gerado;

```html
         <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><small>Paysandu PA x Juventude  </small> </div>
                <div class="panel-heading"><small>27/07/2016 19:30 (quarta-feira) </small> </div>
            </div>



            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                    Vencedor do Encontro
                </a>
                <br />

<form action="/Possibilidade/GravarRegistro" method="post">                            <div class="container">

                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    Casa | R$ 01,73
                                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field VALORAPOSTA1 must be a number." data-val-required="O campo VALORAPOSTA1 é obrigatório." id="item_VALORAPOSTA1" name="item.VALORAPOSTA1" placeholder="valor " type="text" value="0" />
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    Empate | R$ 03,60
                                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field VALORAPOSTA2 must be a number." data-val-required="O campo VALORAPOSTA2 é obrigatório." id="item_VALORAPOSTA2" name="item.VALORAPOSTA2" placeholder="valor " type="text" value="0" />
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    Fora | R$ 04,20
                                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field VALORAPOSTA3 must be a number." data-val-required="O campo VALORAPOSTA3 é obrigatório." id="item_VALORAPOSTA3" name="item.VALORAPOSTA3" placeholder="valor " type="text" value="0" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar para o caixa" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                                    <input type="reset" name="btnLimpar" id="btnLimpar" value="Limpar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
</form>
             </div>
```

Comment: Cigano Morrison, poderia me ajudar com o seu grande conhecimento? agradeço

Comment: Como ficou o HTML gerado desses formulários?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, adicionei o hmtl, mais está gerando certo, veja ai, eu estou usando o IEnumerable porque eu estou criando um formulário para cada linha de registro, porque em alguns casos eu vou ter mais de 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *Binding* está errado. Veja o nome dos `id`s e dos `names`.

```
id="item_VALORAPOSTA1" name="item.VALORAPOSTA1"
id="item_VALORAPOSTA2" name="item.VALORAPOSTA2"
id="item_VALORAPOSTA3" name="item.VALORAPOSTA3"
```

Para funcionar, o *Binding* tinha que ser assim:

```
id="VALORAPOSTA1" name="VALORAPOSTA1"
id="VALORAPOSTA2" name="VALORAPOSTA2"
id="VALORAPOSTA3" name="VALORAPOSTA3"
```

Isto se resolve colocando seu formulário numa *Partial*, por exemplo:

### _Formulario.cshtml

```
@model Generico.Dominio.TB_POSSIBILIDADE

@using (Html.BeginForm("GravarRegistro", "Possibilidade", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO01) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR01)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO02) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR02)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA2, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => Model.VALOR03)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar para o caixa" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
            <input type="reset" name="btnLimpar" id="btnLimpar" value="Limpar" class="btn btn-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

E o `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Formulario", item)
}
```

Comment: A sua resposta foi perfeita, funcionou, só fiquei com uma pequena dúvida,  os valores que são preenchidos na tela como VALORAPOSTA1
VALORAPOSTA2 e VALORAPOSTA3, são enviados para o controle, mais alguns campos que são apenas descrição que já vem preenchido do banco estão passando vazio, como exemplo Model.DESCRICAO01 e Model.VALOR01, tem como pegar estes valores também?

Comment: Tem. Você precisa colocar os campos no formulário também, mas não vejo muita utilidade em salvar descritivos. Ainda assim, se você realmente precisa mandar esses campos para o *Controller*, use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` ou `@Html.HiddenFor()`, se não quiser que eles apareçam.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria mudar a forma como você está renderizando a caixa de texto, invés de:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
```

Tente assim:

```
@Html.TextBox("VALORAPOSTA1", item.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
```

Fazendo assim, o nome do controle vai corresponder ao nome da propriedade da sua classe de *Model* e ao fazer o *POST* você receberá os valores no *Controller*.

Comment: eu agradeço a sua resposta, mais eu preferi fazer usando o partial, mais se puder me ajudar nisso:  alguns campos que são apenas descrição que já vem preenchido do banco estão passando vazio, como exemplo Model.DESCRICAO01 e Model.VALOR01, tem como pegar estes valores também?

Comment: Uma vez que você obtém os campos na sua Controller, você deve preencher sua classe de Model. Depois na sua View você insere os campos com o mesmo nome da propriedade do seu Model, aí quando você fizer o Post ele envia os campos. Ou seja, você faria praticamente da mesma forma como você fez com o campo VALORAPOSTA1. Mas, quando você não quer que o campo seja editável você não usaria um TextBox, mas outro controle apenas para mostrar o texto e um controle que vai armazenar o valor e será útil para enviá-lo no Post,@Html.HiddenFor() , por exemplo.